# memory bandwidth bottle neck

Tags: amazon-ec2, memory, bandwidth

I have a python pandas program. When I run on AWS Ec2 with 8 cores. I got 100% CPU utilization and program finished in 8 minutes. Then if I go 16 cores, I can only get 50% CPU utilization and program still finish in 8 minutes. I suspect it hits memory bandwidth bottle neck so I selected X1,16xlarge instance which has 64 cores and claimed memory bandwidth of 300GB/s. However, it didn't help. the program used a tiny percentage of the 64 cores and didn't finished even after 10 minutes.
[ec2 X1 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/memory-optimized-instances.html)

Any idea what's going on?

(by the way, the same program running on my old desktop tower with 4 cores finished in 16 minutes)

more details: the program uses GridSearchCV which then uses [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) to run multi-processing in parallel. Number of process always equals to the number of cores in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a "global interpreter lock" that limits its ability to utilize multiple threads efficiently. One [responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312109/multithreading-for-data-from-dataframe-pandas) on this site that you should consider writing time critical functions in C/C++.

If possible, consider breaking your analysis into smaller chunks and then run them as separate processes to avoid the global interpreter lock issue.

Comment: This is a great point but I am not sure it was what happened to me. Let me add more details to the original question. Thanks.

Comment: I checked every process that joblib starts. There is only one thread attached.